# Update or Replacement for Identity Server in ABP

Tags: .net, keycloak, identityserver4, abp

ABP currently seems to use IdentityServer 4 (according to the [documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/IdentityServer)).

Since Version 4 is not the youngest anymore, are there any plans to update it or replace it with e.g. Keycloak or something?

Or is it possible to 'replace' IdentityServer by your own with e.g. Keycloak?

Didn't try anything, since i'm still evaluating ABP's features and how it could match into my development.

Comment: This may be of some help: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/11989

Answer (score 1):

Abp templates are already migrated to [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) after v6. [AbpOpenIddictModule](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Modules/OpenIddict) is built on top of OpenIddict library.

We do keep supporting AbpIdentityServer module (which uses IdentityServer4 library) that you can keep using but we  don't have any plans to update to Duende IdentityServer v5 or v6 at the moment (more details at https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/11989)

If you want to migrate from IdentityServer to OpenIddict, you can check https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Migration-Guides/OpenIddict-Step-by-Step

We are also working on seamless ways to integrate standalone authentication servers like Keycloak.